# Node: Upload to S3 Fails Only on the First Trail

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm using `aws-sdk` in node to do let my webapp talk to aws s3 buckets. When trying to upload a file to s3 for the first time in a while, it fails; if I tried to upload again immediately, it works.

After some debugging, seems it's a problem with `requestUrl`:

The first trial tries to send request directly to

`requestUrl: https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/`,

which of course leads to 403 forbidden error.

The other successful requests target at

`requestUrl: https://my-bucket.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/querystrings....`

which is the correct url.

Now my question is, why is only the first trial gets to wrong `requestUrl`? In the server the signed url is generated as:

`const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  params: {
    Bucket: "my-bucket",
  },
});`


`s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', {
   Key: s3Key,
   ContentType: newFile.type,
   ACL: 'private',
})`

Btw the credentials to the s3 bucket are automatically loaded from the `IAM role` of the `ec2` server, and the bucket is set to allow `GET` and `PUT` from that role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I can't say for certain that this is the issue, there is a caveat in the documentation specifically mentioning IAM roles:

> Note: You must ensure that you have static or previously resolved credentials if you call this method synchronously (with no callback), otherwise it may not properly sign the request. If you cannot guarantee this (you are using an asynchronous credential provider, i.e., EC2 IAM roles), you should always call this method with an asynchronous callback.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property

It would make sense that this would resolve itself in subsequent runs, because the async attempt to obtain the role credentials would likely have succeeded in the background by the second call.